# Sending emails in different languages using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, email, templates, thymeleaf, translation

I am sending emails using Thymeleaf. I've set up the templates that I need and it works perfectly. I'm now trying to translate this email depending on the receiver's language. I know the language I need to use through a previously recovered variable.
I'm using properties files to set up the variables that will be translated.
So far, I have three languages: French, English, and Chinese. So I have three properties files :

- mail.messages_fr_FR
- mail.messages_en_US
- mail.messages_zh_CN

I have the following methods in my email configuration class :

```
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource emailMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("mailMessages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }
```

I have enabled the Mvc :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class AccessRequestEventHookApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

I have a method in my email configuration class which is the following :

```
    public void sendMessageUsingThymeleafTemplate(String to, String subject, Map<String, Object> templateModel, String appName)
        throws MessagingException {

        Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
        thymeleafContext.setVariables(templateModel);
        String htmlBody;
        if (appName == "Test1"){
            htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process("Test1-template", thymeleafContext);
        } else {
            htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process("Test2-template", thymeleafContext);
        }
    sendHtmlMessage(to, subject, htmlBody);
    }
```

This function is then called in my controller.
I also have my template resolver and engine as follow :

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("mail-templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
        return templateEngine;
    }
```

I tried changing the locale resolver type with cookie, acceptLanguage, it still does not work.

If I change the language on my computer (from French to English for example), it works, the English translation is used. But I can't figure out how to change the locale variable directly in the code.
As it is sent to a user, I can not base myself on their locale.

If I was not clear, please let me know and I will provide any info needed.

Thanks !

Comment: How do you trigger Thymeleaf to create the email HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the locale on the `Context` object you create for Thymeleaf:

```
Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
thymeleafContext.setLocale(locale);
```

If you are calling your `sendMessageUsingThymeleafTemplate` method from a web controller, you can do this as well:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  private final ServletContext servletContext;

  public MyController(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public void myControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                 Locale locale) {
    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);
    context.setLocale(locale);

    service.sendMessageUSingThymeleafTemplate(context, ...);
  }
}
```